# calling zoomReset on the GraphicalView object does not work

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I would like to implement my own button to reset the zoom.

When calling the zoomReset on the active GraphicalView object (received from the chartfactory, and displayed currently on the screen), the view should change and it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set the external zoom.
Check this [link](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.html#setExternalZoomEnabled%28boolean%29) out for details.